# Speak better than I

Tags: comparisons

I have no idea what the correct option is from the following:

1. Most of the people speak better English than I do German.
2. Most of the people speak better English than my German.
3. Most of the people are better at English than I am at German.
4. Most of the people speak better English than I German.

4 is weird. 3 feels superfluous. 2 mixes a verb and a possessive.

Comment: Your 1st and 3rd options both seem natural to me; 2 seems to lose the parallel structure for comparison, and the elision of the verb in 4 takes a little processing time.

Comment: 'Most of the people' seems weird. Try 'Most people'.

Comment: What @9fyj'j55-8ujfr5yhjky-'tt6yhkjj said.  And #1

Comment: I was trying to derive this phrase for "most of my colleagues" but thought to make it more generic.

Answer (score -1):

1,2,3 sound natural to me, 4 sounds awkward reminds me of someone from several decades or perhaps 1800s speaking. In written I wouldn't bat an eye to the fourth sentence but I dont think anyone in my region would ever say that.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Comment: I upvoted, so, some people must really be against your explanation.

Comment: @mcalex, nothing to explain here, they sound weird. Im not sure why, I just would never say them. Although I agree "most people" is more natural than most of the people. Without a doubt #4 no one would ever say where I live.